# What does the <= expression mean?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, momentjs

So I have seen something like the code below in a React-Redux application

```
return StartTime <= currentTime && currentTime <= EndTime;
```

What exactly does this line returns to? What does the <= mean?

Comment: *Smaller or equal than*. That line return a boolean (true or false). The line just test if `currentTime` is between `StartTime` and `EndTime`, both included.

Comment: Oh!! pshh, I was so used to the error function in React like () => {}, so I thought it is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "less than or equal to" operator.
Example:

```
return 3 <= 3 && 4 <= 5 //true&&true - true
return 3 <= 2 && 4 <= 5 //false&&true - false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the [less than or equal to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than_or_equal) operator.

```
1 <= 2 // true
1 <= 1 // true
1 <= 0 // false
```